# How to make NSFetchedResultsController return more sections?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I watch some sample code and apple document , it all appears the fetchedResultsController always have one section count .

How to make it return two sections ?

Cause the real problem is , i am doing an iOS To-do apps. 
There is finished/To do job list , saved in core data , show in `UITableview` as two sections.

But there is only one fetchedResultsController, how to make it support two sections ?

This is official sample code , i don't know how to change this .

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger count = [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];

    if (count == 0) {
        count = 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a `sectionNameKeyPath` when constructing the FetchedResultsController. In your case that could be `finished` if you have that attribute on your Entity.

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/initWithFetchRequest%3amanagedObjectContext%3asectionNameKeyPath%3acacheName%3a)

Update:

You would initialize a NSFetchedResultsController like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:manangedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"category" cacheName:nil];
```

Make sure that the `sortDescriptors` in your `fetchRequest` provide the same ordering as your `sectionNameKeyPath` does.

You can access the section's name like this:

```
id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections[section];
NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionInfo name];
```

Comment: The correct name of the parameter is `sectionNameKeyPath`. And don't forget to add a (first) sort descriptor using the same key.

Comment: could you give us a example ?